# How to use sides of a sprite rect in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am attempting to draw a line between two different instances of the same sprite class, the sprite class being coded in as shown here (this is just the `__init__` function):

```
class Atom(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
"""Creates an atom of an element.
 The element can be specified using the element parameter.
 This will take a dict argument, contained in a constants file of some sort."""
def __init__(self, element, centre_loc):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
    pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(self.image, 15, 15, 14, (0, 255, 0))
    pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(self.image, 15, 15, 14, (0, 255, 0))


    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.center = centre_loc
    self.element = element
    self.show_text(element)
    self.print_properties(self.element)
```

I have tried to do this using the code here:

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, color, sprite.rect.right. sprite.rect.left)
```

I have simplified the above code, to highlight what I have actually done.
The actual code for the above is found [here](https://github.com/ModoUnreal/pyelement/blob/master/amide.py), it is commented out on line 25. The rest of the code can also be found in that repository for reference.

I had hoped that this would work however I got this error instead:

`TypeError: Invalid start point argument`

So what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sprite.rect.left` and `sprite.rect.right` and not valid points because they are each a single integer. What you probably want is `sprite.rect.topleft` and `sprite.rect.topright`, or the bottom or mid equivalents.

Comment: So would `sprite.rect.midleft` or `sprite.rect.midright` work as well, or is there another way of getting the mid equivalents?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. [This](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) page provides a complete list of methods and attributes available for rect objects.

Comment: I just tested `midleft` and `midright` and it works! Thanks so much!